# Reference/translation request: Doaudy and Hubbard

Tags: reference-request, complex-dynamics, translation-request

Does anyone know where to find an english translation of

Adrien Douady, John Hubbard - Etudes dynamique des polynomes complexes I & II, Publ. Math. Orsay. (1984-85) (The Orsay notes)

It is clearly a foundational paper as it is cited all over the place, yet I can only find it in the original French.

Comment: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf perhaps